# Print biggest len of several lists

Tags: python, list

I have several lists in one list and I want to compare the length of the lists and print the list with biggest number of `len`.

example:

```
somelist = [['a','b','c'],['a','b']]
```

the first list has a bigger len (3) than the second list (2), how do I print this in python?

Comment: So what is the expected output? `3` or `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: I think OP wants only the length not the list that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
max(len(l) for l in somelist)
```

This calculates the length for each sublist and returns the largest one.

If instead you wanted to extract the list with the longest length itself (so `['a', 'b', 'c']` rather than `3`, use `len` as the `key` argument:

```
max(somelist, key=len)
```

Demo:

```
>>> somelist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']]
>>> max(len(l) for l in somelist)
3
>>> max(somelist, key=len)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```